# Magento CE 1.9 backorders do not produce message in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, backorder

We are using Magento CE 1.9. I am having a problem. I am trying to enable backorders with customer notification. I have set

*System - Configuration - Inventory - Product Stock Options - Backorders"* set to "**"Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer"** for every product I have set *Manage Stock* to **"Yes"** *Stock Availability* to **"In Stock"**

Backorders are accepted, but there is no notification in the cart associated with the products that are backordered.

All products visible in the catalog are configurables.

My question is a two-part one. First, am I doing something wrong? I.e. is there something else I need to set up?

Second, if I'm doing everything right where would I look for the code that should be producing this notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the second part of your question
https://www.alphachannelgroup.com/magento-backorders-complete-with-notifications-to-customers/

Modify Your Theme File to Display a Custom Backorder Message

In [your theme]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

Add `echo $backorder_message;` right after the `endif` of the section that starts with `// Backorder message` comment

(EDITED OUT)

About the first part of your question try the following steps (you have done some of these, but still):

1. Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Catalog Tab > Inventory > Product Stock Options
2. Set Backorders to "Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer"
3. Edit Product to Qty to the number of current in-stock quantity (or 0 if there are no quantities for this product in stock)
4. Set Stock Availability = In Stock
5. Set Manage Stock to "Yes"
6. Set Qty for Item’s Status to Become Out of Stock to negative number of the backorder availability (e.g. the number up to which you want to allow back ordering)

   UPDATE core_config_data 
   SET value = ‘-100’ 
   WHERE path = ‘cataloginventory/item_options/min_qty’

Sources:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-enable-backorders/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288259/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuring-inventory-information

Comment: The System => Configuration => etc. is set up properly.  I think the problem may be a sort of Catch-22.  Although I set up all of my products with "In Stock" Stock Availability, as they are depleted and the Qty falls below 0 they are marked "Out of Stock" automatically.  I wonder if I could set the Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock to a large negative number.

Comment: They fall bellow 0, because you have manage stock = yes. Set it to No and try again. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuring-inventory-information - idea is to make product permanently available but as backorderable product

Comment: But if we turn off stock management don't we completely lose track of stock?  We want to take backorders on stock that's being maintained, not eliminate stock management entirely.

Comment: OK, in this case, set negative value for "Qty for Item’s Status to Become Out of Stock" http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288259/ and try again. Edited out the answer to include this discussion so far.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try.

Comment: It will NOT allow me to put a negative number there.  UPDATED:  based on the link you gave me it CANNOT be done via Admin but can be done via direct database update. I'll see it I can do that.

Comment: please let me know if any luck

Comment: Here's what I did.  Since I couldn't set the value to a negative number in the backend, I went in and edited it directly in the mySQL database.  I then forced all of the products in the catalog to "In Stock" (since any that had fallen to zero had automatically been marked "Out of Stock".  I haven't had an opportunity to check what that did yet but I'll report on it as soon as I know

Comment: That seems to have done it.  AFter FORCING the admin config value for "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" to a large negative number (in my case by using phpMyAddmin), I have verified that I am actually able to accept backorders.  This is rather clearly a Magento bug.  The backend should allow you to set that value to a large negative number and my understanding it that it used to.  Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **system > configuration** and on the left side panel  click on **inventory** tab under **Catalog** tab and then open **product stock option** section 
and set **Heading BackOrders** drop down menu to **ALLOW QTY BELOW 0 AND NOTIFY CUSTOMER**